# Find the object with the longest string

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting list of objects from an external service of the form:

```
[
    {
      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'C13',
      'Object': 'car',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
    },
    {
      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'C13',
      'Object': 'own car',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
    },
    {
      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'C13',
      'Object': 'road',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_ON'
    },
    {
      'Sentence': 'Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'Kunal',
      'Object': 'own car',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
    },
    {
      'Sentence': 'Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'Kunal Mukherjee',
      'Object': 'own car',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
    }
]
```

---

**So my aim is to filter the objects from the response which contain each other**,

```
{
  'Sentence': 'Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.',
  'Subject': 'Kunal',
  'Object': 'own car',
  'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
},
{
  'Sentence': 'Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.',
  'Subject': 'Kunal Mukherjee',
  'Object': 'own car',
  'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
}
```

In the above objects in the `Subject` property the longest common string is `Kunal Mukherjee` so only that object needs to filtered.

**Another example**:

```
{
  'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
  'Subject': 'C13',
  'Object': 'car',
  'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
},
{
  'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
  'Subject': 'C13',
  'Object': 'own car',
  'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
}
```

Here in the `Object` property `own car` is the longest common string out of the two, so it should be taken.

---

**So, the final filtered list must look something like this:**

```
[
    {
      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'C13',
      'Object': 'own car',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
    },
    {
      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'C13',
      'Object': 'road',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_ON'
    },
    {
      'Sentence': 'Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.',
      'Subject': 'Kunal Mukherjee',
      'Object': 'own car',
      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
    }
]
```

---

So I am trying like this to compare each `ith` and `i+1th` element for the rule that:

- If `ith` element's `Subject` contains `i+1th` element `Subject` take
  it and vice-versa.
- If `ith` element's `Object` contains `i+1th`
  element `Object` take it and vice-versa.

but its not panning out correctly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string data = @"[
                    {
                      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
                      'Subject': 'C13',
                      'Object': 'car',
                      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
                    },
                    {
                      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
                      'Subject': 'C13',
                      'Object': 'own car',
                      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
                    },
                    {
                      'Sentence': 'C13 can travel by own car on road.',
                      'Subject': 'C13',
                      'Object': 'road',
                      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_ON'
                    },
                    {
                      'Sentence': 'Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.',
                      'Subject': 'Kunal',
                      'Object': 'own car',
                      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
                    },
                    {
                      'Sentence': 'Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.',
                      'Subject': 'Kunal Mukherjee',
                      'Object': 'own car',
                      'Relation': 'CAN_TRAVEL_BY'
                    }
                  ]";

    List<JObject> js = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(data);

    var pairs = js.Take(js.Count - 1).Select((x, i) =>
    {
        string aSubj = js[i]["Subject"].ToString();
        string bSubj = js[i + 1]["Subject"].ToString();


        string aObj = js[i]["Object"].ToString();
        string bObj = js[i + 1]["Object"].ToString();

        if ((aSubj.Length > bSubj.Length && aSubj.Contains(bSubj)) || (aObj.Length > bObj.Length && aObj.Contains(bObj)))
        {
            return js[i];
        }
        if ((aSubj.Length > bSubj.Length && aSubj.Contains(bSubj)) || (bObj.Length > aObj.Length && bObj.Contains(aObj)))
        {
            return js[i + 1];
        }

        return js[i];
    }).ToList();
}
```

---

This is the [.NET fiddle](https://rextester.com/CQWIYA69308) to test this.

Any help is appreciated to help me solve this.

Comment: What if one item has longer `Subject` and another item has longer `Object`?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear on what you are exactly looking for... I understand what you receive, but I don't get what you want from that data...

Comment: The idea being adjacent `Subject(s)` and `Object(s)` need to be compared for longest matches

Comment: @KunalMukherjee `adjacent` criteria do not exist in your question

Comment: @MartinVerjans I am constructing a graph database by taking natural language and splitting them via Stanford CoreNLP service which gives me response in the following form

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy no I mean the consecutive `ith` and `i + 1th` element needs to be compared for which string contains the other.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy updated the question

Comment: It looks like you want to GroupBy  : Subject, Object, Relation.  Then eliminate the sentences  where "a" is contained in "b".

Comment: @jdweng Not exactly `GroupBy`, but checking if the `i-th` and `i+1th`elements' `Subject` and `Object` property are contained in another and filter them accordingly.

Comment: checking the i-th and i-th+1 is what I meant by iterating through the ith array and doing a contains.  The Grouping if you want to use Subject, Object, Relation or just two of the three.

Comment: Yeah basically group by `Subject`, `Object` and `Relation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create (extension) method which reduce (filters) your items:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> Reduce(this IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    using (var iterator = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var next = iterator.Current;
            var containsPrevious =
                previous.Sentence == next.Sentence &&
                next.Subject.Contains(previous.Subject) &&
                next.Object.Contains(previous.Object);

            if (!containsPrevious)
                yield return previous;

            previous = next;
        }

        yield return previous;
    }
}
```

The rule is simple - when adjacent items have the same sentence and latter item includes subject and object of the previous item, then discard the first item from results.

Usage is simple:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(data).Reduce();
```

Note that you need `Item` class (consider using better names)

```
public class Item
{
    public string Sentence { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Object { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Sentence": "C13 can travel by own car on road.",
    "Subject": "C13",
    "Object": "own car",
    "Relation": "CAN_TRAVEL_BY"
  },
  {
    "Sentence": "C13 can travel by own car on road.",
    "Subject": "C13",
    "Object": "road",
    "Relation": "CAN_TRAVEL_ON"
  },
  {
    "Sentence": "Kunal Mukherjee can travel by own car on road.",
    "Subject": "Kunal Mukherjee",
    "Object": "own car",
    "Relation": "CAN_TRAVEL_BY"
  }
]
```

Comment: 2 questions, 1) `while (iterator.MoveNext())` how does the iterator goes back ? 2) Why `previous = next;`

Comment: Iterator goes only forward that's why I keep the previous item. `previous = next` to store current item for next iteration